# Firebase cloud functions - update a different object within OnUpdate cloud trigger

Tags: firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, transactions

Assume there is a collection of users and each user is associated with accounts, which are kept in a separate collection. For each account there is a balance which is updated periodically by some external means (e.g. the http trigger below). I need to be able to query for the user's total balance across all of her accounts.

I added onUpdate trigger which gets called everytime an account changes and updates the total accordingly. However, it seems that there is some race condition e.g. when two accounts get updated around the same time: after onUpdate is called for the first account and updates the total balance, it is still not updated when onUpdate is called for the second account. I'm guessing I need to somehow use "transaction" for the bookkeeping but not sure how.

```
 const data = {
    'users/XXX': {
      email: "a@b.com",
      balance: 0
    },
    "accounts/YYY": {
      title: "Acc1",
      userID: "XXX"
      balance: 0
    },
    "accounts/ZZZ": {
      title: "Acc2",
      userID: "XXX"
      balance: 0
    }
  };

exports.updateAccounts = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  admin.firestore().collection('accounts').get().then((accounts) => {
    accounts.forEach((account) => {
      return admin.firestore().collection('accounts').doc(account.id).update({balance: 
WHATEVER});    
    })
 response.send("Done");
});

exports.updateAccount = functions.firestore
    .document('accounts/{accountID}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const userID = change.after.data().userID;
      admin.firestore().doc("users/"+userID).get().then((user) => {
        const new_balance = change.after.data().balance;
        const old_balance = change.before.data().balance;
        var user_balance = user.data().balance + new_balance - old_balance;
        admin.firestore().doc("users/"+userID).update({balance: user_balance});
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your code we can see several parts of it that could lead to incorrect results. It is not possible, without thoroughly testing and reproducing your problem, to be sure at 100% that correcting them will totally solve your problem but it is most probably the cause of the problems.

### HTTP Cloud Function:

With the `forEach()` loop you are calling several asynchronous operations (the `update()` method) but you don't wait that all these asynchronous operations are completed before sending back the response. You should do as follows, using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait all the asynchronous methods are completed before sending the response:

```
exports.updateAccounts = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const promises = [];
  admin.firestore().collection('accounts').get()
  .then(accounts => {
      accounts.forEach((account) => {
        promises.push(admin.firestore().collection('accounts').doc(account.id).update({balance: WHATEVER}));
      return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(() => {
      response.send("Done");
  })
  .catch(error => {....});
});
```

### `onUpdate` background triggered Cloud Function

There you need to correctly return the Promises chain in order to indicate to the platform when the Cloud Function is complete. The following should do the trick:

```
exports.updateAccount = functions.firestore
    .document('accounts/{accountID}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

      const userID = change.after.data().userID;

      return admin.firestore().doc("users/"+userID).get()  //Note the return here. (Note that in the HTTP Cloud Function we don't need it! see the link to the video series below)
      .then(user => {
        const new_balance = change.after.data().balance;
        const old_balance = change.before.data().balance;
        var user_balance = user.data().balance + new_balance - old_balance;
        return admin.firestore().doc("users/"+userID).update({balance: user_balance});  //Note the return here.
      });
});
```

---

I would suggest that you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/. They explain all the key points that were corrected above.

---

At first sight, it seems that if you modify, in the `updateAccounts` Cloud Function, several `account` documents that share the same `user` you will indeed need to implement the user balance update in a transaction, as several instances of the `updateAccount` Cloud Function may be triggered in parallel. The doc on Transactions is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

**Update:**
You could implement a Transaction as follows in the `updateAccounts` Cloud Function (untested):

```
exports.updateAccount = functions.firestore
.document('accounts/{accountID}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {

    const userID = change.after.data().userID;

    const userRef = admin.firestore().doc("users/" + userID);

    return admin.firestore().runTransaction(transaction => {
        // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
        return transaction.get(userRef).then(userDoc => {
            if (!userDoc.exists) {
                throw "Document does not exist!";
            }

            const new_balance = change.after.data().balance;
            const old_balance = change.before.data().balance;
            var user_balance = userDoc.data().balance + new_balance - old_balance;

            transaction.update(userRef, {balance: user_balance});
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
        return null;
    });   

});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don't wait for the results in the HTTP Cloud Function because I don't really care about it - it's just a means to test changes to the underlying objects. But in production I will have some trigger that updates multiple accounts at the same time (doesn't have to be in a single transaction as they are independent). I guess the question remains - how can I call the transaction you mentioned within the onUpdate function? Can you please show an example?

Comment: thanks a lot - this was very helpful and worked great. Please only change userDoc to userRef in the transaction.update line and I will mark it as the answer :-)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Just a question, looking at the `onUpdate` code, we don't need to do use `return` if we are using `async await` syntax right?

Comment: If you use async/await you should return "something" (e.g. `return null;`) when all the asynchronous work is completed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [@Renaud Tarnec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3371862) covered in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60600779/3068190), you may also want to consider the following approaches:

## Batched Write

In your `updateAccounts` function, you are writing many pieces of data at once, if any one of these fail, you may end up with a database that contains a mix of correctly updated data and data that had failed to be updated.

To solve this, you can use a batched write to write the data atomically where all new data is updated successfully or none of your data is written leaving your database in a known state.

```
exports.updateAccounts = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  db.collection('accounts')
    .get()
    .then((qsAccounts) => { // qs -> QuerySnapshot
      const batch = db.batch();
      qsAccounts.forEach((accountSnap) => {
        batch.update(accountSnap.ref, {balance: WHATEVER});
      })
      return batch.commit();
    })
    .then(() => response.send("Done"))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error whilst updating balances via HTTP Request:", err);
      response.status(500).send("Error: " + err.message)
    });
});
```

## Splitting the counters

Instead of storing a single "balance" in your document, it may instead be desirable (based on what you are trying to do) to store each account's balance in the user's document.

```
"users/someUser": {
  ...,
  "balances": {
    "accountId1": 10,
    "accountId4": -20,
    "accountId23": 5
  }
}
```

If you need the cumulative balance, just add them together on the client. If you need to remove a balance, simply delete it's entry in the user document.

```
exports.updateAccount = functions.firestore
  .document('accounts/{accountID}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const accountID = context.params.accountID;
    const newData = change.after.data();

    const accountBalance = newData.balance;
    const userID = newData.userID;
    return db.doc("users/"+userID)
      .get()
      .then((userSnap) => {
        return db.doc("users/"+userID).update({["balances." + accountID]: accountBalance});
      })
      .then(() => console.log(`Successfully updated account #${accountID} balance for user #${userID}`))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error whilst updating account #${accountID} balance for user #${userID}`, err);
        throw err;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman. I don't think the Batch Write is required here because those balances are independent and there is no requirement for all of them to be updated at once. In fact there are different types of accounts and they may be updated separately by different triggers. Splitting the counters and summarizing on the client is an option I'll think about. I'm still interested though in how to solve the original question, even if I end up not using it here...;-)

Comment: @shaimo Whilst the batch write might not be required, it's a preventative measure to ensure data integrity of your database. The purpose of the batch write is to ensure that either 0% or 100% of your updates are applied. Using Promise.all() leads to the possibility that anywhere between 0-100% of your data is written and you won't know what was successful and what wasn't without modifying your code to track it.

Comment: following up just to make sure I'm not missing something - since the different accounts are independent, the data should be consistent even if only some of them get updated. This is why I don't think I need it to be batched. In any case in the production code I'll make it a habit to make updates consistent where required.

Comment: @shaimo I've written a better explanation with an example [on Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/CEAYCKns) that may make it easier to understand. It didn't make sense to include it in the answer here. Based on what you said in the most recent comment, Option 2 is likely the way to go.